# What is the meaning of ";" symbol in config file lines?

Tags: pulseaudio, configuration

I was editing the PulseAudio `daemon.conf` file and I saw some lines starting with the `;` symbol (image attached).

[image: daemon.conf file contents]

What is the meaning and use of this symbol in the configuration file's lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the very screenshot you shared. "Use either ; or # for commenting" hehe